# Convert List of Names to Integer Labels in R

Tags: r

Consider the following list

```
names = c("Bob", "Steve", "John", "Steve")
```

I would like a function that returned an integer for each unique name

```
int_names = [1,2,3,2]
```

and a dictionary so I can then go back to the names

```
dict_names = ["Bob", "Steve", "John"]
```

I can see how to do this with a for loop but I am sure there must be a more efficient way to do this in R. I think it may be something to do with `factor` but I only seem to be able to get `int_names` using this and lose `dict_names`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `unique` and `match`

```
 dict_names <- unique(names)
 int_names <- match(names, dict_names)
```

Or with `factor` by specifying the `levels` as 'dict_names`

```
 int_names <- as.numeric(factor(names, levels=dict_names))
```

Comment: Do you know if match is using a hash table to do the matching for the `match` function?

Comment: @MikeWise No, I don't know about it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you get it by adding names to an atomic vector. No additional functions necessary.

```
samplenames <- c("Bob", "Steve", "John","Steve")
thesenames <- unique(samplenames)
idx <- 1:length(thesenames)    
names(idx) <- thesenames

idx["Steve"]  # is 2
idx["John"]  # is 3
```

and

```
thesenames[1] # is "Bob"
thesenames[2] # is "Steve"
```

Comment: I don't understand your solution. If OP has `set.seed(123) ; thesenames <- sample(c("Bob", "Steve", "John"), 10, replace = TRUE)` how is your solution deals with it? For example, @akruns solution will be `dict_names <- unique(thesenames) ; match(thesenames, dict_names)`. But I don't see any solution on your side here.

Comment: Then you would need an additional step, like this. I didn't think it was a random vector: `set.seed(123) ; samplenames <- sample(c("Bob", "Steve", "John"), 10, replace = TRUE);thesenames <- unique(samplenames);idx <- 1:length(thesenames);names(idx) <- thesenames; idx["Steve"];idx["Bob"]`

Comment: Ok, I hadn't understood that aspect of the question, I thought the double "Steve" was an edit error. The idea still works though.

Answer (score 1):

```
names <- c("Bob", "Steve", "John", "Steve")
names.factor <- as.factor(names)
names.integer <- as.integer(names.factor)
names.dict <- unique(cbind(names.factor,names))
```